# Laravel 4 - No matter what code I put I get an error with my css page

Tags: css, view, laravel, laravel-4

No matter what I put in a css page that I am using for an edit-order view I keep getting the same "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" on the first line of code and cannot figure where I am going wrong. Any and all assistance figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

I, assuming that my css code was incorrect, tried several different snippets of code such as

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

,

```
a {
    color: #8D0D19;
    }
```

, and

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

individually and still received the same error code.

I thought that I had made a mistake with the call to the CSS but I have a jquery UI css file that is working fine and checked this site to make sure I was doing it (one of) the right way(s), but nonetheless here is the relevant section of my View::

```
{{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::style('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); }}
    {{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/js/edit_order.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/css/main.css') }}
```

Any idea or explanation on where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to include your style sheet as a style sheet, not as a script:

```
{{ HTML::style('/css/main.css') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  {{ HTML::style('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); }}
```

This line has an extra semicolon after the ) remove it and it should work just fine.